# React export React.createContext not defined

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to learn React Context and got stuck. Need help.

**App.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import Header from './components/Header';

export const MyContext = React.createContext("Default");

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <MyContext.Provider value="dark">
        <Header />
      </MyContext.Provider>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

**Header/index.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { MyContext } from "./../../App";

class Header extends Component {
    //static contextType = MyContext;
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {this.context}
            </div>

        )
    }
}

Header.contextType = MyContext;
export default Header;
```

Got an error **MyContext is not defined**.
It works when i move Header class to App.js

What am i doing wrong? Tnx for your help

Comment: You only have a `Provider` you need a `Consumer` to get your value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The provider only holds the the value for you(a bit like a store). It is the consumer that makes it available to your components.

Headerjs should look like this

```
// Header.js
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { MyContext } from "./../../App";

class Header extends Component {
    //static contextType = MyContext;
    render() {
        return (
          <MyContext.Consumer>
            { value => {
              return <div>
                {value}
              </div>
            }}
         <MyContext.Consumer>
        )
    }
}

// Header.contextType = MyContext; not needed for react v16+
export default Header;
```

To get more power out of `Context` i will suggest combining with Higher Order Components. for example if what you want is a theming system
you can do this.

```
import React from "react";

const themes = {
  dark: {
    background: "#333"
  },
  light: {
    background: "#f5f5f9"
  }
};

const { Provider, Consumer } = React.createContext(themes);

export const ThemeProvider = ({ children }) => {
  return <Provider value={themes}>{children}</Provider>
};

export const withTheme = theme => {
  return Component => props => <Consumer>
      {themes => {
        return <Component {...props} style={{ ...themes[theme]}} />;
      }}
  </Consumer>
};
```

in **`app.js`**

```
import Header from "./Header";
import { ThemeProvider } from './Theme'
class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <ThemeProvider>
        <Header />
      </ThemeProvider>
    );
  }
}
```

and lastly **`Header.js`**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { withTheme } from "./Theme";

class Header extends Component {
  //static contextType = MyContext;
  render() {
    return <h1 style={{ ...this.props.style }}>Header</h1>;
  }
}

export default withTheme("dark")(Header);
```

You can read **MY**  [article on using context for auth for more](https://medium.com/belly-of-the-beast/put-it-in-context-9a2ba0f82133)

Answer (score 1):

There are **two** ways to use context either use:

**1.** By using context consumer :

```
 <MyContext.Consumer>
    { 
       contextValue => {
              return <div>
                {value}
              </div>
         }
     }
 <MyContext.Consumer>
```

**2.** By assigning context to a object:

```
static contextType = MyContext;
render(){
  const {value1,value2.......} = this.context
}
```

For more information about **Context** visit the React official page.
https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html